# 1 user with 2 firebase database information

Tags: xcode, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: sample image]

Hello, Im trying to figure out on how to show the 2 cars of the same user in a tableView. Is that possible?

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "driverRequestCell", for: indexPath)

    if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {

        Database.database().reference().child("Driver").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let driverRequestDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                if let typeOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["car"] as? String {

                    cell.textLabel?.text = typeOfCar

                }
            }
        })
    }
    return cell

}
```

Comment: That definitely should be possible. Can you show what you've tried already?

Comment: Hi FrankvanPuffelen, sorry for the late reply. I think our timezones are different. I'va updated the question that i ask above. I added the code that i used. hope to hear from you soon. thanks

Comment: The Firebase code looks fine. Since you observe `.childAdded` your closure block will be called twice: once for each car. But since you only have one text label, the second `typeOfCar` will replace the first one.

Comment: so does that mean i should change the observe .childAdded?

Comment: Not at all. Since you have two cars that match the query, it will just be called twice. But you will either need two cells in the table (one for each car), or add information about both cars to one cell.

Comment: oh ok. I got the part about the two cells, but that will be more confusing, i just solve some of the problems just by watching tutorials online. im just a begginer. hahahaha. Is there a way that i can call the same "email" under the "Drivers" so that i can get the details of the "cars"?

Comment: You're already getting all the cars. If you change the setting of the label to `cell.textLabel?.text = cell.textLabel?.text  + typeOfCar` you will see both. Or just `print(typeOfCar)` (since I'm not a Swifty myself, my code is to be taken with a grain of salt).

Comment: what do you use when you code? Is it easier?

Comment: I've figure it out. I added let snapshot = self.jdriverRequests[indexPath.row]. the print(typeOfCar) also works but it will only be shown at the bottom part. Thanks for your help @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Good to hear that you found it. If you post the code of your solution as an answer, others can benefit from it. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Is coding really like this, like after solving a new problem, you have a new one. hahahaha

Comment: Pretty much. It wouldn't be nearly as much fun otherwise.  I consider it an endless puzzle. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "driverRequestCell", for: indexPath)


if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {

    Database.database().reference().child("Driver").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        //just add this line
        let snapshot = self.driverRequests[indexPath.row]

        if let driverRequestDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

        if let typeOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["car"] as? String {

                cell.textLabel?.text = typeOfCar

            }
        }
    })
}
return cell

}
```